# Люди or человек after numerals?

Tags: склонение, существительные, числительные

From what I know, the plural noun "people" is **люди** when no numeral precedes it. Whereas "people" preceded by a numeral take the stem **человек-**, as in **два человека**, **пять человек** (the latter example meaning that "человек" is also an irregular genitive plural).

In the aforementioned examples, the numeral is in the nominative case. If number 2 ever takes the animate accusative case (which does not concern numbers from 5 forth), then we'll get **двух человек** which is usable either for the genitive or accusative case of this numeral-noun sequence.

But what if I ever want to write a numeral-people sequence in other cases? I namely want to tell *"between two people"*. Will it become **Между двумя человеками**?

Someone told me it should be rather "**Между двух людей**", an expression which, if correct, then adds up to the long list of irregularities in the Russian language, since **между** takes the instrumental case by default, and **людей** is being used after a numeral.

So, which is the right word for "people" after a numeral taking the dative, instrumental or prepositional cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Firstly**, with numerals (cardinal numerals) plus noun we should use **only the root человек** in all cases. The conjugation is as follows:

И кто? два, три, четыре человека, пять, шесть и т.д. человек

Р кого? двух человек, пяти человек

Д кому? двум человекам, пяти человекам

В кого? двух человек, пять человек

Т кем? двумя человеками, пятью человеками

П о ком? о двух человеках, о пяти человеках

But (**Secondly**)

If there is an **adjective** between the numeral and the noun we can use **both человек и людей** in all cases after пять, шесть etc. and after два , три etc. in all cases but nominative (only человек).

пять незнакомых человек и пять незнакомых людей, не было и трех взрослых человек и не было и трех взрослых людей

**Thirdly**

The preposition между can be used with the **genitive and instrumental** cases, so между двух человек и между двумя человеками. The preference depends on the context.

**Four**

There are **words which show quantity, but they are not numerals**.

Пять человек. Десять человек. Сто человек. This should be already clear. When we have a numeral , we use человек.

Десятки людей. Тысячи людей.Миллионы людей.When we have noun +noun , we use людей. And the number here is not exact.

Сто человек , but сотня людей. Миллион человек , but миллионы людей.

Грамота,ру. , Русская грамматика/Институт русского языка при АН. 1980.

Comment: Dear downvoters, care to leave comments, svp. The source is more than reliable.

Comment: Grammatical correctness is a social matter, of approving certain ways of speech and not others. What's "correct" depends on where you live, what languages you speak, and who you interact with.

Comment: "Толпа не менее сотни человек" (толковый словарь Кузнецова). "Сотни человек вышли на санкционированное шествие и митинг к Министерству иностранных дел в Праге". "Пара человек". And so on and so on...

Comment: As to why books on Grammar do so poor a job at teaching even native speakers, maybe they were so intent on making sure non-native learners don’t generate ungrammatical patterns that they’ve forgotten to teach how colloquial system itself works more generally.

Comment: Пара is two,  не менее сотни is 101,102 etc. So человек is correct. But сотни людей, not человек вышли... I could not cover the whole chapter. Books are not to blame. People are. Besides, do you usually care what words you choose? I don't think so. Because for you  it doesn't usually matter. It should though for those who write or for those who learn your language.

Comment: "Пара" is a noun. "Пара людей" - I can't even take this in. "Не менее сотни" is "не менее сотни". It can be 100. 101, 102...it's just your conjecture. One can swap "толпа не менее сотни человек" with "толпа в сотню человек". "Толпа в сотню людей" sounds odd.  " Пять незнакомых человек" but " пятеро незнакомых людей".  Sorry, but your valid source doesn't work to the fullest.

Comment: Try to find a more respectful source than АН. Thanks for your commemts anyway.